# HTML How to allow browser to save a Text input as password

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my static **Login** webpage,

I wanted to change my `<input type="password">` box's font to a custom `@font-face` but couldn't so I changed it to `<input type="text">` and continued to complete my webpage.

My `@font-face` ,custom font, is a set of stylized gibberish symbols and I want to use instead of the default `*` symbols that generates by default while typing text.

Now I am want to allow the user to save his/her password in their browser but the browser doesn't give a save password option when I submit my form as both inputs are of type text. Is there any way I can do this?

EDIT: 
MY HTML:

```
<form id="loginform" action="#" method="get">
            <label for="uname"> Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="user" name="uname" id="uname" value="" placeholder="UserName" />
            <label for="pass">Password</label>
            <input type="text" class="paswd" name="pass" id="pass" value=""  placeholder="Password"/>
            <input type="submit" name="name" value="Submit" />
      </form>
```

MY CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'webfontregular';
    src: url('myfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('myfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
.paswd{
  font-family: 'webfontregular';
}
```

EDIT 2: I found a temporary solution which I have tested in firefox

used the following java-script

```
  var FormSubmit = function (){
    document.getElementById('pass').setAttribute("type", "password");
    document.getElementById('loginform').submit();
  }
```

With adding a button to my HTML

```
<input type="button" value="Click this" onclick="FormSubmit()" />
```

Slow connection speed will change the font of my password, so is there any permanent solution?

Comment: Please add a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, see also stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Every browser should give You API to internal CredentialsManager so You could call him with JS. Example :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsILoginManager/Using_nsILoginManager

Comment: where's the input type=password you talk about ? can you set up a fiddle ?

Comment: @Take_Care_ - I don't think that API would be available to a web page :p

Comment: best solution - change it back to password and live with the browsers font choice

Comment: @saru95 — There is no password input. The OP said *I changed it to `<input type="text">`*

Comment: do you mean anythink like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/3fkNJ/1/

Comment: @Provie9 no not like that..

Answer (score 0):

here is a work around for you. add a password input field with style **display:none & type="password"** and on **input event** of your text type password field update value of password field like below. browser will prompt to save the password when the form is submitted.

```
    $(function(){
        $('#pass').on('input', function(){
            $('input[type="password"]').val(this.value);
        });
    });

    <form id="loginform" action="#" method="get">
                <label for="uname"> Username</label>
                <input type="text" class="user" name="uname" id="uname" value="" placeholder="UserName" />
                <label for="pass">Password</label>
                <input type="text" class="paswd" name="pass" id="pass" value=""  placeholder="Password"/>
      <input name="pwd" id="pws" value=""  type="password"/>
                <input type="submit" name="name" value="Submit" />
          </form>
```

Comment: can you noob-ify it for me? with exact code which i will require